# What are the most advanced techniques to test Android projects?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-studio

I'm trying to learn a bit of Android, and I've been reading a lot of documentation and tutorials.

I decided to use what seemed at that moment the most straight path, and that was use Android Studio. The first hacking hours went OK, the IDE is something that I like and I was able to build some activities.

Now I want to make things more serious and start to unit test the application. I must confess that I'm incredibly lost between the different paths that people is following. Please, if any question or assertion is wrong, let me know.

- The basic testing tools that Android provide, needs to be used launching the emulator. This makes the tests run slow.
- The are other approaches like Roboelectric. They have done a huge work and it would let you launch the tests from the terminal with Gradle and you can get a faster cycle (Red, Green, Refactor). Anyway, there are known problems using it with Android Studio and if sometime I need to debug a test, I won't be able.

I feel like I'm struggling a lot with something that should be very basic. I guess that my lack of knowledge in Java isn't helping. Something that it would be great and desirable as features of my project would be:

- Be able to run some tests (business logic) with jUnit. Those tests should be fast and it would be great to run them from the terminal and from the IDE.
- Be able to have others, isolated, integration tests (as you can see in the Android documentation).

I would like to know how people who is working in big projects are dealing with this. Any link to better documentation that I found or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!